# SonarQube Web API authentication in Java

Tags: java, api, sonarqube, authorization, token

I'm trying to use SonarQube 7.9.1 CE Web API to retrieve some information from the server in a Java Spring Boot application, and I have started with a very simple one: the list of projects.

It turns out that I need to provide my identity information, via token or via user/password combination. But official documentation and StackOverflow answers only show a CURL request as example:

```sh
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:9000/api/components/search_projects
curl -u 9548utj958tju5498jt934: http://localhost:9000/api/components/search_projects
```

I've been trying to use **RestTemplate** to send the request, but I always get a 401 UNAUTHORIZED error.

How should I send the user token?
In a request header? As part of the request parameters? No one says.

I've tried to do it via **Authorization** header using **Bearer 9548utj958tju5498jt934**, **Basic 9548utj958tju5498jt934**, inserting a parameter in the request and nothing works.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/web-api/)?

Comment: Yes, @jeroen-heier, that was exactly the problem, that there are no language-specific demos, only a CURL example. I figured out what the problem was: a colon needs to be added to the end of the token before encoding it to base64, and then the encoded string can be sent as a request header:

encodedToken = Base64.encode((token + ":").getBytes());
Authorization("Basic " + encodedToken)

This is an aproximation to code, I don't remember the exact syntax now
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to put the ":" character after the token.
If you take a look at the documentation, you will see:

> # note that the colon after the token is required in curl to set an empty password 
>   curl -u THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN: https://sonarqube.com/api/user_tokens/search

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/web-api/

So, in order to make it work in the java app you will have to do this:

`String tokenBase = userToken + ":";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(tokenBase.getBytes()));
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);`

This worked for me!

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Thanks a lot!